# Wordpress set featured image with custom post type

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

In wp-admin, I create a new admin menu page.

```
add_menu_page('My custom post page type title', 'My custom post type menu', '', 'my-custom-slug', '', '', 99);
add_submenu_page('my-custom-slug', 'Add new', 'Add new', 'manage_options', 'post-new.php?post_type=my-custom-post-type', '');
```

I want to use the panel like post-new.php and edit.php so I registered a custom post type.

```
register_post_type('my-custom-post-type', 
                   array('labels'=>array('name'=>__('Products','text-domain'),
                                         'singular_name'=>__('Product','text-domain'),
                                         'menu_name'=>_x('Products','Admin menu name','text-domain'),
                                         'add_new'=>__('Add Product','text-domain'),
                                         'add_new_item'=>__('Add New Product','text-domain'),
                                         'edit_item'=>__('Edit Product','text-domain'),
                                         'new_item'=>__('New Product','text-domain'),
                                         'view_item'=>__('View Product','text-domain'),
                                         'not_found'=>__('No Products found','text-domain'),
                                         'not_found_in_trash'=>__('No Products found in trash','text-domain')),
                         'supports'=>array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments')
                         'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'mscases'),
                         'public'=>true,
                         'capability_type'=>'post'));
```

The custom menu page works fine, and the meta box `Featured Image` works fine too, I can pick image in media library.

After I choose an image, it doesn't appear on Featured Image meta box, and the `admin-ajax.php` response is -1 ( I check the post page, It is zero if success ).

But if I change the parameter `my-custom-post-type` to `product` ( like woocommerce ), the featured image I pick up will appear.

Is there any thing I miss in coding?

Answer (score 0):

Replace and try

```
register_post_type('my-custom-post-type',
    array('labels' => array('name' => __('Products', 'text-domain'),
            'singular_name' => __('Product', 'text-domain'),
            'menu_name' => _x('Products', 'Admin menu name', 'text-domain'),
            'add_new' => __('Add Product', 'text-domain'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Product', 'text-domain'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Product', 'text-domain'),
            'new_item' => __('New Product', 'text-domain'),
            'view_item' => __('View Product', 'text-domain'),
            'not_found' => __('No Products found', 'text-domain'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Products found in trash', 'text-domain')),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mscases'),
        'public' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you creating the custom post type never use the '-' sign please use '_' instead of '-'.

I have same problem in past and i have changed and it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Googling about this issue, finally I found out the problem is.

You have to use the `add_action` and set the hook as `init`.

Such as `add_action('init', array('MyClass', 'RegisterPostType'));`

And the featured image works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell WordPress first that your theme supports featured image by placing this at functions.php :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'umbrella_theme_setup' );
function umbrella_theme_setup(){
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
```

And than you need to enable featured image on custom posts :

```
register_post_type('my-custom-post-type', 
                   array('labels'=>array('name'=>__('Products','text-domain'),
                                         'singular_name'=>__('Product','text-domain'),
                                         'menu_name'=>_x('Products','Admin menu name','text-domain'),
                                         'add_new'=>__('Add Product','text-domain'),
                                         'add_new_item'=>__('Add New Product','text-domain'),
                                         'edit_item'=>__('Edit Product','text-domain'),
                                         'new_item'=>__('New Product','text-domain'),
                                         'view_item'=>__('View Product','text-domain'),
                                         'not_found'=>__('No Products found','text-domain'),
                                         'not_found_in_trash'=>__('No Products found in trash','text-domain')),
                         'supports'=>array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments')
                         'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'mscases'),
                         'public'=>true,
                         'capability_type'=>'post'));
```

Featured image meta should appear now on your custom posts and `the_post_thumnail();` functions should work.'
And you have to remove the sub_menu_page and menu_page as WordPress shows a UI for them so you don't have to prepare one.